# How can I run OV5647_mipi on iMX8QXP

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, imx6, imx7

Hi I have iMX8QXP kit and I want to get stream from ov5647 camera.

DISTRO = fsl-imx-wayland.

My ov5647 camera's pin connected to :

MIPI_CSI0_ACM_MCLK_OUT         MIPI_CSI0_MCLK_OUT           ALT0

MIPI_CSI0_CKN                                        MIPI_CSI0_CLK_N                   ALT0
MIPI_CSI0_CKP                                        MIPI_CSI0_CLK_P                    ALT0
MIPI_CSI0_DN0                                        MIPI_CSI0_DATA0_N                ALT0
MIPI_CSI0_DN1                                        MIPI_CSI0_DATA1_N                ALT0
MIPI_CSI0_DN2                                        MIPI_CSI0_DATA2_N                ALT0

MIPI_CSI0_DN3                                        MIPI_CSI0_DATA3_N                ALT0
MIPI_CSI0_DP0                                        MIPI_CSI0_DATA0_P                ALT0
MIPI_CSI0_DP1                                        MIPI_CSI0_DATA1_P                ALT0
MIPI_CSI0_DP2                                         MIPI_CSI0_DATA2_P               ALT0
MIPI_CSI0_DP3                                         MIPI_CSI0_DATA3_P               ALT0

But I2C pins not connected. Is it problem? Can I get datas from camera without init via i2c?

So I can't find these pins (with pad signal names) in ./include/dt-bindings/pinctrl/pads-imx8qxp.h and if I write these pins pad format I get error instead of write MIPI_CSI0_ACM_MCLK_OUT. I think this pins dedicated and I can't mux. I can use directly without change scfw.

So my dts file about mipi csi camera :

---

```
&iomuxc {
imx8qxp-mek {
pinctrl_mipi_csi0: mipicsi0grp{
fsl,pins = <
SC_P_MIPI_CSI0_MCLK_OUT_MIPI_CSI0_ACM_MCLK_OUT 0xC0000041
SC_P_MIPI_CSI0_GPIO0_01_LSIO_GPIO3_IO07 0xC0000041
SC_P_MIPI_CSI0_GPIO0_00_LSIO_GPIO3_IO08 0xC0000041
>;
};

pinctrl_parallel_csi: parallelcsigrp {
fsl,pins = <
SC_P_CSI_D00_CI_PI_D02 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_D01_CI_PI_D03 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_D02_CI_PI_D04 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_D03_CI_PI_D05 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_D04_CI_PI_D06 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_D05_CI_PI_D07 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_D06_CI_PI_D08 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_D07_CI_PI_D09 0xC0000041

SC_P_CSI_MCLK_CI_PI_MCLK 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_PCLK_CI_PI_PCLK 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_HSYNC_CI_PI_HSYNC 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_VSYNC_CI_PI_VSYNC 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_EN_LSIO_GPIO3_IO02 0xC0000041
SC_P_CSI_RESET_LSIO_GPIO3_IO03 0xC0000041
>;
};
};
};

&isi_0 {
interface = <6 0 2>; /* INPUT: 6-PARALLEL CSI */
parallel_csi;
status = "okay";
};

&cameradev {
parallel_csi;
status = "okay";
};

&parallel_csi {
#address-cells = <1>;
#size-cells = <0>;
status = "okay";
port@0 {
reg = <0>;
parallel_csi_ep: endpoint {
remote-endpoint = <&ov5647_ep>;
};
};
};

&isi_2 {
interface = <2 0 2>;
status = "okay";
};

&isi_1 {
status = "disabled";
};

&isi_3 {
status = "disabled";
};

&isi_4 {
status = "disabled";
};

&isi_5 {
status = "disabled";
};

&isi_6 {
status = "disabled";
};

&isi_7 {
status = "disabled";
};

&i2c0_csi0 {
clock-frequency = <100000>;
status = "okay";
#address-cells = <1>;
#size-cells = <0>;
ov5647_mipi: ov5647_mipi@36 {
compatible = "ovti,ov5647_mipi";
reg = <0x36>;
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_mipi_csi0>;
clocks = <&clk IMX8QXP_24MHZ>;
clock-names = "csi_mclk";
csi_id = <0>;
pwn-gpios = <&gpio3 7 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
rst-gpios = <&gpio3 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
mclk = <24000000>;
mclk_source = <0>;
mipi_csi;
status = "okay";
port {
ov5647_mipi_ep: endpoint {
remote-endpoint = <&mipi_csi0_ep>;
};
};
};

/delete-node/max9286_mipi@6A;
};

&mipi_csi_0 {
/delete-property/virtual-channel;
status = "okay";
#address-cells = <1>;
#size-cells = <0>;
port@0 {
reg = <0>;
mipi_csi0_ep: endpoint {
remote-endpoint = <&ov5647_mipi_ep>;
data-lanes = <1 2>;
};
};
};
&i2c0_cm40 {
#address-cells = <1>;
#size-cells = <0>;
ov5647: ov5647@36 {
compatible = "ovti,ov5647";
reg = <0x36>;
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_parallel_csi>;
clocks = <&clk IMX8QXP_PARALLEL_CSI_MISC0_CLK>;
clock-names = "csi_mclk";
pwn-gpios = <&gpio3 2 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
rst-gpios = <&gpio3 3 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
csi_id = <0>;
mclk = <24000000>;
mclk_source = <0>;
status = "okay";
port {
ov5647_ep: endpoint {
remote-endpoint = <&parallel_csi_ep>;
};
};
};
};
```

Then I open ov5647_mipi support via make menuconfig :

make menuconfig > Device Drivers > Multimedia Support > V4L platform devices > MXC Camera/V4L2 RPR Features Support > Omnivision ov5647 camera support using mipi > (*).  I add y to here.

Than I boot, there is no new video in /dev. (with or without ov5647 driver not change video size. There are video12 and video13)

And I change Omnivision ov5647 camera support using mipi to m (build module) and I insmod ov5647_camera_mipi.ko

module loaded and strace like that :

```
brk(NULL) = 0x1b168000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=43413, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 43413, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xffff8ba94000
close(3) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\300$\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=88392, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffff8ba92000
mmap(NULL, 151928, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xffff8ba4c000
mprotect(0xffff8ba61000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xffff8ba70000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0xffff8ba70000
close(3) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\260C\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1405888, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1477872, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xffff8b8e3000
mprotect(0xffff8ba33000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xffff8ba43000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x150000) = 0xffff8ba43000
mmap(0xffff8ba49000, 11504, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffff8ba49000
close(3) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffff8b8e1000
mprotect(0xffff8ba43000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0xffff8ba70000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x42f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0xffff8baa1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0xffff8ba94000, 43413) = 0
brk(NULL) = 0x1b168000
brk(0x1b189000) = 0x1b189000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="imx8qxpmek", ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/modules/4.19.35-1.1.0+g0f9917c56d59/modules.softdep", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/cmdline", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 ro rootwait "..., 4095) = 88
read(3, "", 4007) = 0
close(3) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, ".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ov5647_camera_mipi.ko", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=28736, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ov5647_camera_mipi.ko", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177E", 2) = 2
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=28736, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 28736, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xffff8ba97000
finit_module(3, "", 0) = 0
munmap(0xffff8ba97000, 28736) = 0
close(3) = 0
exit_group(0) = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

and I tried video12 and video13 to open camera via lvds with these commands :

Command :

gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=ball \    ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 \    ! videoconvert \    ! tee \    ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video12
Output :

root@imx8qxpmek:/home# gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=ball \

> ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 \
>   ! videoconvert \
>   ! tee \
>   ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video12
>   Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
>   ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0: Device '/dev/video12' is not a output device.
>   Additional debug info:
>   ../../../git/sys/v4l2/v4l2_calls.c(687): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0:
>   Capabilities: 0x4204000
>   Setting pipeline to NULL ...
>   Freeing pipeline ...

root@imx8qxpmek:/home#

---

Command :

gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=ball \    ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 \    ! videoconvert \    ! tee \    ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video12
Output :

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, interlace1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, interlace-mod1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, interlace1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:tee0.GstTeePad:src_0: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, interlace-mode=(string1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, interlace-mode=(1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:tee0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, interlace-mode=(string)pro1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, interlac1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, interlace-mo1
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock

^Chandling interrupt.  -------------------------------------> CTRL + C
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:01:03.000609625
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

---

command :

gst-launch-1.0 -e glvideomixer name=mix background=3 sink_0::xpos=192 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_0::width=640 sink_0::height=480 sink_0::zorder=1 ! "video/x-raw,width=1024,height=768" ! glimagesink rotate-method=horizontal-flip v4l2src device=/dev/video13 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! mix.sink_0 &

output :

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'sink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"(GstGLDisplayWayland)\ gldisplaywayland0";
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../../../../git/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
EOS on shutdown enabled -- waiting for EOS after Error
Waiting for EOS...

---

command :

gst-launch-1.0 -e glvideomixer name=mix background=3 sink_0::xpos=192 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_0::width=640 sink_0::height=480 sink_0::zorder=1 ! "video/x-raw,width=1024,height=768" ! glimagesink rotate-method=horizontal-flip v4l2src device=/dev/video12 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! mix.sink_0 &

Output :

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
Got context from element 'sink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"(GstGLDisplayWayland)\ gldisplaywayland0";
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Device '/dev/video12' is not a capture device.
Additional debug info:
../../../git/sys/v4l2/v4l2_calls.c(679): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
Capabilities: 0x4204000
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

Help please. I am waiting your suggestion.

---

Edit 1 :

I change dts file like that :

```
&iomuxc {
    imx8qxp-mek {
        pinctrl_mipi_csi0: mipicsi0grp{
            fsl,pins = <
                SC_P_MIPI_CSI0_MCLK_OUT_MIPI_CSI0_ACM_MCLK_OUT  0xC0000041
                SC_P_MIPI_CSI0_GPIO0_01_LSIO_GPIO3_IO07     0xC0000041
                SC_P_MIPI_CSI0_GPIO0_00_LSIO_GPIO3_IO08     0xC0000041
            >;
        };

        pinctrl_parallel_csi: parallelcsigrp {
            fsl,pins = <
                SC_P_CSI_D00_CI_PI_D02      0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_D01_CI_PI_D03      0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_D02_CI_PI_D04      0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_D03_CI_PI_D05      0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_D04_CI_PI_D06      0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_D05_CI_PI_D07      0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_D06_CI_PI_D08      0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_D07_CI_PI_D09      0xC0000041

                SC_P_CSI_MCLK_CI_PI_MCLK        0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_PCLK_CI_PI_PCLK        0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_HSYNC_CI_PI_HSYNC      0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_VSYNC_CI_PI_VSYNC      0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_EN_LSIO_GPIO3_IO02     0xC0000041
                SC_P_CSI_RESET_LSIO_GPIO3_IO03  0xC0000041
            >;
        };
    };
};

&isi_0 {
    interface = <6 0 2>;    /* INPUT: 6-PARALLEL CSI */
    parallel_csi;
    status = "disable";
};

&cameradev {
    mipi_csi_0;
    status = "okay";
};

&parallel_csi {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    status = "disable";
    port@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        parallel_csi_ep: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&ov5647_ep>;
        };
    };
};

&isi_2 {
    interface = <2 0 2>;
    status = "okay";
};

&isi_1 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&isi_3 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&isi_4 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&isi_5 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&isi_6 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&isi_7 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&i2c0_csi0 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    status = "okay";
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    ov5647_mipi: ov5647_mipi@36 {
        compatible = "ovti,ov5647_mipi";
        reg = <0x36>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_mipi_csi0>;
        clocks = <&clk IMX8QXP_24MHZ>;
        clock-names = "csi_mclk";
        csi_id = <0>;
        pwn-gpios = <&gpio3 7 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        rst-gpios = <&gpio3 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        mclk = <24000000>;
        mclk_source = <0>;
        mipi_csi;
        status = "okay";
        port {
            ov5647_mipi_ep: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&mipi_csi0_ep>;
            };
        };
    };

    /delete-node/max9286_mipi@6A;
};

&mipi_csi_0 {
    virtual-channel;
    status = "okay";
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    port@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        mipi_csi0_ep: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&ov5647_mipi_ep>;
            data-lanes = <1 2>;
        };
    };
};
&i2c0_cm40 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    ov5647: ov5647@36 {
        compatible = "ovti,ov5647";
        reg = <0x36>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_parallel_csi>;
        clocks = <&clk IMX8QXP_PARALLEL_CSI_MISC0_CLK>;
        clock-names = "csi_mclk";
        pwn-gpios = <&gpio3 2 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        rst-gpios = <&gpio3 3 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        csi_id = <0>;
        mclk = <24000000>;
        mclk_source = <0>;
        status = "disabled";
        port {
            ov5647_ep: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&parallel_csi_ep>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

now I seems modules : 
root@imx8qxpmek:/# find -name "*ov5647*"
./sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ov5647_mipi
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/i2c@37230000/ov5647@36
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/i2c@58226000/ov5647_mipi@36
./sys/module/ov5647_camera_mipi

and when ls /dev there is two /dev/video now. (video0 and video1).

Why there is two video channel now?

Also there is an error about my dts file.
What is that :

root@imx8qxpmek:/# dmesg | grep ov5

[    3.667601] ov5647_mipi 16-0036: Error applying setting, reverse things back
[    3.674673] ov5647_mipi: probe of 16-0036 failed with error -22

I am waiting for some help.

---

Edit 2 : 
I deleted

```
        SC_P_MIPI_CSI0_GPIO0_01_LSIO_GPIO3_IO07     0xC0000041
        SC_P_MIPI_CSI0_GPIO0_00_LSIO_GPIO3_IO08     0xC0000041
```

from dts file. (I think there was pin conflict)

```
root@imx8qxpmek:/# dmesg | grep ov5
[    3.641815] ov5647_mipi 16-0036: 16-0036 supply DOVDD not found, using dummy regulator
[    3.649866] ov5647_mipi 16-0036: Linked as a consumer to regulator.0
[    3.656255] ov5647_mipi 16-0036: 16-0036 supply DVDD not found, using dummy regulator
[    3.664175] ov5647_mipi 16-0036: 16-0036 supply AVDD not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.751720] ov5647_read_reg:write reg error:reg=300a
[    4.756696] camera ov5647_mipi is not found
root@imx8qxpmek:/#
```

Also I try video0, video1 and video12 with this command :

```
root@imx8qxpmek:/# gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video12 glimagesink                                                                                                                                   
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
Got context from element 'sink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayWayland\)\ gldisplaywayland0";
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Device '/dev/video12' is not a capture device.
Additional debug info:
../../../git/sys/v4l2/v4l2_calls.c(679): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
Capabilities: 0x4204000
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
root@imx8qxpmek:/#
```

But video13 different :

```
root@imx8qxpmek:/# gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video13 glimagesink                                                                                                                                   
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'sink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayWayland\)\ gldisplaywayland0";
Caught SIGSEGV
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
#0  0x0000ffffbce2a1a0 in __GI___poll (fds=0x13944c50, nfds=2, 
#1  0x0000ffffbcf4b22c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x0000ffffbcf4b640 in g_main_loop_run () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x0000ffffbd0da5bc in gst_bus_poll () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#4  0x0000000000404828 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000004036a8 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000ffffbcd89264 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4032c0, argc=4, 
#7  0x0000000000403d44 in ?? ()
Spinning.  Please run 'gdb gst-launch-1.0 4434' to continue debugging, Ctrl-C to quit, or Ctrl-\ to dump core.
```

Now again I am waiting for some help!!